# Help with WFS Filter request

Tags: wfs, filter, cql-filter

I'm trying to download all features from this WFS: [capabilities](https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?SERVICE&service=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities), [describefeaturetype](https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?SERVICE&service=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType)

It's working fine with the most simple requests like: [getfeatures](https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?SERVICE&service=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=Bathy2017_2_raster:EL.GridCoverage&outputformat=application/json&maxFeatures=100)

But now, I need >all< features in the dataset, but the service won't allow me to do so since the maxFeatures is set to 100 (serverside). Now, I'd want to create some sort of quadtree to iterate through the data. But therefore I need a boundingbox filter. I found some examples like;[ogcfilter](https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&typeNames=Bathy2017_2_raster:EL.GridCoverage&crs=EPSG:3857&Filter=%3Cogc:Filter%3E%3Cogc:BBOX%3E%3Cogc:PropertyName%3EShape%3C/ogc:PropertyName%3E%3Cgml:Box%20srsName='urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857'%3E%3Cgml:coordinates%3E51.1007179,1.6869819,52.769873,4.275398099999999%3C/gml:coordinates%3E%3C/gml:Box%3E%3C/ogc:BBOX%3E%3C/ogc:Filter%3E)

and one using a cql_filter:[cqlfilter](https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&typeNames=Bathy2017_2_raster:EL.GridCoverage&crs=EPSG:3857&cql_filter=(bbox(geom,1.6869819,51.1007179,1.8275398099999999,52.769873,'EPSG:3857'))

None of them is working. Is there someone who can guide me in the right direction? I'd like to know how to use the boundingbox filters, but still, ultimately I'm looking in downloading >all< features within a certain boundingbox.

Edit:
I also tested the WFS server in QGIS. Without enabling the viewport as a boundingbox, it works fine. As soon as I say I want only the data within the viewport, it gives an error on the bbox... Is this maybe a server-side problem? Or is it just the QGIS method doesnt work on this specific Service?

Comment: @iant, read GetCapabities and find that ImplementsResultPaging is "false".

Comment: also, I still need to get my bbox-filter working for specifying my area of interest.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be a very clever WFS, you might be best ringing the contact guy and asking if he could install a proper WFS like GeoServer or MapServer which will handle version negotiation, filters and paging for free

Comment: `it gives an error on the bbox`  The service doesn't advertise BBOX as a spatial operator, in fact it doesn't specify support for any `SpatialOperator` (like BBOX) or any `ComparisonOperator`

Comment: @iant thanks, that makes sense (unfortunately..) I'll be contacting the provider then. Then I still have one question; the Capabilities say it 'ImplementsSpatialFilter'. If bbox is not one of them, what is it representing?

Comment: Please edit your GetFeature with filter so that people can fast read it a plain text. Then it  should be obvious that if schema says `<xsd:element name="Geometry" type="gml:PointPropertyType" nillable="false"/>` then a Bbox filter with `ogc:PropertyName=Shape` just can't work.

Comment: The service is implementing the EL GML encoding example from https://themes.jrc.ec.europa.eu/file/group/1793/all and it serves elevation model (DEM) as GML and points. I would consider that it is sort of a demo.

Comment: KVP BBOX seems to work, try https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&typeNames=Bathy2017_2_raster:EL.GridCoverage&crs=EPSG:3857&BBOX=500294.05987,6746705.88996,590294.05987,6946705.88996. And I suggest to avoid Box but write the BBOX filter with Envelope as in here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/problem-with-wfs-filters-bbox-intersects.

Comment: This gives a shorter answer https://inspire.caris.nl/server/services/ows/download/feature/bathymetrie-noordzee_IDS?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application/json&typeNames=Bathy2017_2_raster:EL.GridCoverage&crs=EPSG:3857&BBOX=500294.05987,6746705.88996,500394.05987,6746715.88996. It is best to test filters which use the native projection, in this case EPSG:3857. The coordinates in your filter are probably in EPSG:4326.

Comment: @user3018 wow, that is the most simple answer I could get, and simply overlooked.. thanks!